# Need help. Apple's Reachability class with address does not work

Tags: iphone, xcode, networking, ip-address, reachability

I want to check if my camera is connected, but I can't seem to get this to work.
I have added the Reachability .h and .m. I would appreciate all your help for my school project!

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

Reachability *reachabilityForCam = [Reachability reachabilityWithAddress:struct sockaddr_in callAddress; 
                                     callAddress.sin_len = sizeof(callAddress); 
                                     callAddress.sin_family = AF_INET; 
                                     callAddress.sin_port = htons(80); 
                                     callAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("X.X.X.X")];     
                                     if ([reachabilityForCam currentReachabilityStatus] == NotReachable) {
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Cam is not reachable" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: is this a camera that's on the same wifi network or something?

Comment: Maybe make it more clear what you're trying to do, and what you've tried already, and what errors you've encountered.

Comment: Well, I just want to check if my camera is connected. It is connected to a LAN hub via ethernet cable. What i've done so far is input the reachability classes apple have provided. And i have created a void stated above. The error showing is "Expected expression before 'struct'" I don't even know if what i'm doing so far is correct. Would really appreciate your help

Comment: Well, it's not correct as you're trying to declare and populate a struct in the middle of a method call. Did you read the code from the Apple Reachability project yet?

Comment: Yes i've read it. I tried different ways of doing this.Can't get it to work though.tried this way as well, Reachability*reachabilityForCam = [[Reachability reachabilityWithAddress:@"X.X.X.X"]retain];
 NetworkStatus netStatus = [reachabilityForCam currentReachabilityStatus];
 if ([reachabilityForCam currentReachabilityStatus] == NotReachable) {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Cam is not reachable" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Comment: After inputting this, Reachability reachabilityWithAddress:(const struct sockaddr_in *)hostAddress. How should we input the IP address into this line?

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate you are working on iOS project for your school project. But to check if camera is  available or not you should use [`UIImagePickerController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html) class API not Rechability.

Please check like below.
    `if ([UIImagePickerController isCameraDeviceAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {}`

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for replying. So, I use this method instead of the reachability?

Comment: Please don't mind making the answer correct if that is helpful to you. :)

Comment: I want to make a simple check if the security camera is connected. If it isn't, make a simple alertview. I'm sorry but I don't get the UIImagePickerViewController. I'm a huge noob at this.

Comment: What do you mean by security camera ? Are you talking about iOS device camera ?

Comment: Nope. My school provided me a camera with an ip address.:)

Comment: In that case you need to whatever you are checking with Reachability that is right. Please check you and your school's camera are same network.